# Association references unmapped class: System.Guid

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, guid

I keep getting the exception `Association references unmapped class: System.Guid` with NHibernate 3.1 and FluentNHibernate 1.2.

I'm not sure how this is possible. Isn't the mapping of Guid handled internally?

I saw several previous mentions of a bug in Fluent NHibernate 1.0 and someone mentioned to use trunk instead where it was fixed, but I'm on 1.2 rather than 1.0, so presumably this issue has been resolved.

Edit: Here's some additional information -- an example HBM I've exported from the Fluent AutoMapper looks like the following

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-lazy="false">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" lazy="false" name="Treadmarks.Bus.Frontend.Model.PassType, Frontend, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`PassType`">
    <id name="PassTypeId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="PassTypeId" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Name" />
    </property>

    <property name="UsageInterval" type="System.TimeSpan, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="UsageInterval" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And following is the FNH code that generates said HBM:

```
    private class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
    {
        public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
        {
            return type.Namespace.StartsWith("Treadmarks.Bus.Frontend.Model");
        }

        public override bool IsId(FluentNHibernate.Member member)
        {
            return member.Name == member.DeclaringType.Name + "Id";
        }
    }

    public static Configuration BuildConfiguration()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString("Data Source=Treadmarks.db; Compress=true"))
            .Mappings(
                m => m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), new AutomappingConfiguration())
                                            .Conventions.Add(
                                                DefaultLazy.Never(),
                                                LazyLoad.Never())
                         ).ExportTo("mappings.hbm"))
            .BuildConfiguration();
    }
```

Comment: We're using GUID mapping with no problem. Is it possible to see the line of code that throws the exception?

Comment: Its just a standard BuildSessionFactory call.

Comment: Interesting error message considering `Guid` is a `struct`... seems like a bug in the framework. Have you tried using a different version? (Just for testing this problem, I mean.)

Comment: It works well for me (NH 3.1.0.4000, FNH 1.2.0.712, .NET 4). Please, could you show your original FNH mapping and code that causes the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out FNH can't properly generate mapping for `List<Guid>` like it can for `List<int>`, etc. I'll report this to the FNH team.

Comment: do you know if this was fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message yesterday when wiring up Fluent on a new project.  It is working now (with Guid keys) but I am not able to reproduce the error now.

The message itself conveys that it is looking for mapping configuration for System.Guid.  My best guess is that it's seeing a property name that is triggering its foreign key logic and that property name is associated with a Guid.

Maybe you could add a new foreign key convention so it no longer makes those assumptions with that default logic?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to specificy the type for id mapping, or if you do specify an nhibernate type like 'Guid' see [http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types)